# ADXL354 V1P8ANA

Tags: sensor, analog, accelerometer

I am using an ADXL354 in a circuit, and the part has a voltage output (V1.8ANA) that is the output of the internal LDO which can be used as a reference for an ADC.  I am trying to find out whether I can get a few hundred microamps out of it but there is nothing in the data sheet.  I tried AD support but they responded that it is not to be used externally at all, despite the data sheet.  I am severely constrained for space and these parts are much bigger than the old MEMS accels they are replacing.  The prototype seems ok but I will be building a number of these and they are expensive ($50).  Does anyone out there have any experience in this area?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got a second response from Analog Devices support:  100 uA is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously doubt that you could reliably pull a few 100 uA from it since the total supply current under normal operation is bin rated at 150 uA (see figure 50 in the datasheet). If you are not using the pin to supply voltage to the chip, the datasheet mentions using this output as a reference with an external ADC. That suggests a few uA is the intended external load.